# Connecting to MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, parse-error

can anyone please help me with this, whats wrong with this `php` code ?

according to "http://phpcodechecker.com/" :

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE) in your code on line 7
    $response["products"] = array();`

**get_all_products.php**

```
<?php
$response = array();
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["products"] = array();
 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["price"] = $row["price"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code? Do you get that error?

Comment: I return no errors when I run your code through phpcodechecker.  Have you tried deploying your code on your system yet?  Also, using mysqli_* or PDO would be ideal as the mysql library has been deprecated and is vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: the code works fine, and there is no error on phpcodechecker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/mysql_query

try something like this:

```
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products", $db);
```

Comment: reference link is really helpful